# Нормально ли так хардкодить значения в хранимой функции/приложении?

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, проектирование

Есть хранимая функция, которая принимает несколько аргументов. В ней есть примерно такое условие:

```
IF argument_1 = 2 THEN
        value_to_insert = 32;
ELSE
        value_to_insert = 1;
END IF;
--insert (...,status_id) vaules (...,value_to_insert)
```

В зависимости от аргумента меняется значение для последующей вставки в таблицу.

Или например храдкод в хранимой функции на обновление статуса:

```
IF status_id_in = 9 THEN
--какие-то действия только в этом случаее
ENDIF;
--код
```

Или вот пример хардкода серверной части приложения:

```
if elem.ExpireAt.After(time.Now()){
   UpdateStatus(elem.ID, 45)
   return
}
value := someFunction()
if value > elem.X{
    UpdateStatus(elem.ID, 32)
}else{
    UpdateStatus(elem.ID, 31)
}
```

Мне кажется, что здесь правильно не `ID` статусов кидать, а уникальные имена, которые привязаны к нужному статусу (а потом, в хранимке брать `ID` по имени), но это же тоже храдкод?

Есть ли решения лучше, чем использовать не `ID`, а имена? Или это не хардкод и такая связность нормальная?

Comment: Ну а куда деваться, какой-то хардкод да будет. Но хорошо бы он был в каком-то справочнике, к которому бы обращались все процедуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я когда читаю этот код

```
IF argument_1 = 2 THEN
        value_to_insert = 32;
ELSE
        value_to_insert = 1;
END IF;
--insert (...,status_id) vaules (...,value_to_insert)
```

то у меня сразу возникают вопросы в его правильности. Почему именно эти значения? Что за логика реализована? А правильна ли она? Глядя на прошитые константы это все непонятно.

Гораздо лучше так:

```
IF action = BUY_ACTION THEN
        trade_status = BYING_STATUS;
ELSE
        trade_status = SELLING_STATUS;
END IF;
--insert (...,status_id) vaules (...,trade_status)
```

Именно с этой точки зрения хардкод констант это плохо. Если это реально константа, то она должна быть выражена константой в языке, если есть поддержка в языке (не знаю как в других, это подскажут, вероятно, но в pgplsql есть константы). Так чтоб один раз определить и использовать везде.

Если хранить эти значения в таблице, то:

1. это сбивает с толку, что и не константа это вовсе, а параметр конфигурации.
2. чтоб прочитать их - нужен отдельный запрос, что и по производительности хуже и код усложняется без хорошей причины

Comment: _производительности хуже и код усложняется без хорошей причины_ - но если вызывать хранимую функцию из серверного приложения, то константу в качестве аргумента не передать. И получается или хардкод `UpdateStatus(elem.ID, 32)` или `UpdateStatus(elem.ID, "BYING_STATUS")` а в хранимке `select id from status_list where system_name = 'arg'` (arg = BYING_STATUS)